# destroy gameObject clone if position x and y is the same with my player

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to destroy the gameObject(clone) when my player position x and y is the same with gameObject(clone) position x and y.  The gameObject appear in my scene when I trigger something else and it has rigidbody and box collider.

I use this code to my player, but it doesn't work

```
function Update () {
    if(this.transform.position.x==rigidbody.transform.position.x){
        if(this.transform.position.y==rigidbody.transform.position.y){
            Destroy(rigidbody.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

I used the code and like that but it doesn't work too because it didn't find the variable "other"

```
function Update () {
    var other:Collider;
    if(this.transform.position.x==other.transform.position.x){
        if(this.transform.position.y==other.transform.position.y){
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: You should use OnTriggerEnter and destroy the GameObject with that... You refer to a collider in your update method but that's it... It doesn't reference anything from what I can see... Search tutorials on OnTriggerEnter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what's spawning your clones you could spawn them with different names like "gameObject(clone) 2" and then call Destroy().

```
Destroy(gameObject.Find("gameObject(clone) 2"));
```

In general though as long as you can identify one object from the other this shouldn't be a problem.

If you have reference to the object you do not wan't deleted then you could perform a .Equals to avoid deleting it.

```
// C#
foreach(GameObject go in clones) {
    if(!go.Equals(playerObject) {
        Destroy(go);
    }
}
```

I'd favor the initial approach though. You should have reference or indenifiers for any object in your scene so you can manage them.